# Change billing address when place order

Tags: magento2, magento2.3

I want to Manually change all order address to a specific city. So right now user can just input and city. But I would like to add some validation or change the behavior of save order function. So basically when someone enters a billing address then clicked on the Place Order, I would then change it's city to a default value regardless if they inputted a value in the city. How do I achieve this? I tried using plugin but didn't work. I also tried to override the behavior of `SavePaymentInformationPlaceOrder` but still now luck below is what I did

in my plugin I have this

```
 public function beforeSavePaymentInformationAndPlaceOrder(
    \Magento\Checkout\Api\GuestPaymentInformationManagementInterface $subject,
    $cartId,
    $email,
    \Magento\Quote\Api\Data\PaymentInterface $paymentMethod,
    \Magento\Quote\Api\Data\AddressInterface $billingAddress = null
) {

    $billingAddress->setPersonalMessage("Abc123"); // Personal Message is a custom message that we have
    $billingAddress->save();
    
}
```

And this is the value of my di.xml

```
<type name="Magento\Checkout\Api\GuestPaymentInformationManagementInterface">
    <plugin name="validate-billing-information" type="Vendor\Module\Plugin\Checkout\BillingValidation"/>
</type>
```

The plugin works but when it execute the `Save` method I got this error

```
[2020-09-26 15:37:06] main.CRITICAL: Report ID: webapi-5f6f60228b3a3; Message: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`db_database`.`quote_address`, CONSTRAINT `QUOTE_ADDRESS_QUOTE_ID_QUOTE_ENTITY_ID` FOREIGN KEY (`quote_id`) REFERENCES `quote` (`entity_id`) ON DELETE CASCADE), query was: INSERT INTO `quote_address` (`save_in_address_book`, `prefix`, `firstname`, `lastname`, `company`, `street`, `city`, `region`, `postcode`, `country_id`, `telephone`) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?) {"exception":"[object] (Exception(code: 23000): Report ID: webapi-5f6f60228b3a3; Message: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`db_database`.`quote_address`, CONSTRAINT `QUOTE_ADDRESS_QUOTE_ID_QUOTE_ENTITY_ID` FOREIGN KEY (`quote_id`) REFERENCES `quote` (`entity_id`) ON DELETE CASCADE), query was: INSERT INTO `quote_address` (`save_in_address_book`, `prefix`, `firstname`, `lastname`, `company`, `street`, `city`, `region`, `postcode`, `country_id`, `telephone`) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?) at /home/vagrant/code/vendor/magento/framework/Webapi/ErrorProcessor.php:208, Zend_Db_Statement_Exception(code: 23000): SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`db_database`.`quote_address`, CONSTRAINT `QUOTE_ADDRESS_QUOTE_ID_QUOTE_ENTITY_ID` FOREIGN KEY (`quote_id`) REFERENCES `quote` (`entity_id`) ON DELETE CASCADE), query was: INSERT INTO `quote_address` (`save_in_address_book`, `prefix`, `firstname`, `lastname`, `company`, `street`, `city`, `region`, `postcode`, `country_id`, `telephone`) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?) at /home/vagrant/code/vendor/magento/framework/DB/Statement/Pdo/Mysql.php:110, PDOException(code: 23000): SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`db_database`.`quote_address`, CONSTRAINT `QUOTE_ADDRESS_QUOTE_ID_QUOTE_ENTITY_ID` FOREIGN KEY (`quote_id`) REFERENCES `quote` (`entity_id`) ON DELETE CASCADE) at /home/vagrant/code/vendor/magento/framework/DB/Statement/Pdo/Mysql.php:91)"} []
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try using below event

VendorName/ModuleName/etc/events.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
   <event name="checkout_submit_before">
      <observer name="checkout_submit_before_update_billing" instance="VendorName\ModuleName\Observer\QuoteSubmitBeforeUpdateBilling"/>
   </event>
</config>
```

VendorName/ModuleName/Observer/QuoteSubmitBeforeUpdateBilling.php

```
<?php

namespace VendorName\ModuleName\Observer;

use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;

class QuoteSubmitBeforeUpdateBilling implements ObserverInterface
{
    /**
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer
     * @return void
     */
    public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
    {
        /** @var \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote $quote */
        $quote = $observer->getEvent()->getQuote();
        $quote->getBillingAddress()->setPersonalMessage("Abc123");
    }
}
```

Comment: already tried this but didn't work

Comment: @MadzQuestioning Is the event not getting fired at all or getting fired but not updating the value?

Comment: it's getting fired it's just not updating to the new value I added